# USB is read only when not used with my computer

Tags: permissions, usb-flash-drive

I have a 32GB Sandisk USB flash drive that works great, except for when it is not used ony **MY** user and **MY** computer. If I use it on any other computer, user, or even a Live USB, it is mounted as read-only and I am unable to access the contents.

This is formatted in FAT32 and used primarily for backups that are done with an `rsync` script. It was previously EXT4, but I figured I might want to use it on a windows computer at some point in the future, so I modified the script and formatted the drive to FAT32.

I assume this is some kind of ownership issue? How do I fix it?

Comment: We need more information.

Comment: FAT32 does not have built-in ownership mechanism. Could you please provide details of how exactly (mount options) are you mounting the device in other systems. I strongly believe that this is just a coincidence and has nothing to do with the particular USB stick. Just wrong mounting options. For windows machine, please provide exact error message you are getting.

Comment: Using Linux at the moment. Formatted it and have been using Fedora with GNOME, so it automounts at /run/media/user/USB/.

When I booted to ArchBang on a liveUSB, it did not automount. So I did `mkdir usb` and `mnt /dev/sdb usb/` and got a read-only error. The directory remained empty.

Comment: did you get the error when mounting or when attempting to write to disk after successful mount? If you are failing to mount, then just use `mkdir /home/username/usb` and then `sudo mount -t auto /dev/sdb /home/username/usb`. I think `sudo` was the missing bit here